# Top level links not clickable zurb sites 6

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation, orchardcms-1.9

I'm having a navigation issue with zurb foundation for sites. I've created my menu and any link on the dropdown (sub menus) work just fine. My top level links do not work without any children. The top level links with children can be double clicked and then they work.

Here's my sample page.  http://inside.ipapilot.org/zurbtest.html

In Large or medium context if you click the Home link or any of the top level links, they do not work (except in responsive "small").  The two links with sub menus will work if you double click them, but that's not the UX I want for sure.

The sub links all work just fine.

I am not sure what I have done so wrong here.  I'm trying to create my own Orchard Theme for Zurb Sites 6.3

Thanks for any help!  I'm sure it has something to do with js or how I've tagged something, but I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

There's a good chance this isn't on your end: it seems to be a bug with the interaction between foundation and a recent Chrome update.

There are several foundation bug reports with the drop-down menus and I see at least 2 open bugs with very similar symptoms to what you're describing: [9903](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/issues/9903) and [9811](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/issues/9811). That first link has a workaround that may help: just add a click handler to these top level links that forces the browser to follow the link. Of course this is what should happen by default but adding an explicit click handler may work around the issue without having to patch foundation.js.